# NVIDIA usable memory 4GB instead of 6GB?

Tags: linux-mint, memory, nvidia, dmesg

I have an the following graphics card in my laptop:

**[GPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit): [NVIDIA](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/), [GeForce GTX 1060](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/products/10series/geforce-gtx-1060/), [Max-Q Design](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/gaming-laptops/max-q/), 6 GB [VRAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_RAM_(dual-ported_DRAM))**

I am on Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon 64-bit with NVIDIA drivers version 390 official:

[image: NVIDIA driver 390 official]

You can see for yourself, but I know that from Dell support, I have been assured on Windows there shall be no problem, well on Linux, they don't know. *Sigh* ...

[image: NVIDIA memory 6GB]

---

I used the following command to get the whole output of `dmesg` (just pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> afterwards):

```
\dmesg --human --color=always --ctime --follow > vlastimil-dmesg.log 2>&1
```

It is available on my hosting temporarily, will delete it probably later on: [click to download](https://www.vlastimilburian.cz/public/linux/vlastimil-dmesg.log.xz).

Please check SHA-1 hash sum for your protection:

```
d670f6b883147ad919bb3d341d3c679493189d3f  vlastimil-dmesg.log.xz
```

---

There, I incidentally found, I quote:

> ```
> [Sat Feb  9 15:25:28 2019] [drm] Memory usable by graphics device = 4096M
> ```

What is that? Is that a fact or could it be a *mistake*?

I play games on this device, so it really matters to me.

---

### EDIT1: `nvidia-smi` tool screenshot

[image: <code>nvidia-smi</code> tool screenshot]

What that `dmesg` message means then?

---

The problem has been solved by running multiple games at once with allocated memory of 5148 MiB. Still, I would like to know what that message means then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nvidia-smi` monitoring tool should provide more meaningful information about the available / real memory usage under load.

Try for example:

```
$ watch -n 0.5 nvidia-smi
```

Which updates every 0.5 seconds and see if you can get above 4096 MiB threshold.

With a memory usage > 4096 MiB it should be clear that card can handle all of its 6 GiB.

**Note:**

The "4096M" message is from your Intel i915 graphics card. The nvidia card is initialized after that.

```
root@x250:/mnt/d/tmp# xzless vlastimil-dmesg.log.xz | grep drm
[Sat Feb  9 15:25:28 2019] [drm] Memory usable by graphics device = 4096M
[Sat Feb  9 15:25:28 2019] fb: switching to inteldrmfb from EFI VGA
[Sat Feb  9 15:25:28 2019] [drm] Replacing VGA console driver
[Sat Feb  9 15:25:28 2019] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[Sat Feb  9 15:25:28 2019] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[Sat Feb  9 15:25:28 2019] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin (v1.1)
[Sat Feb  9 15:25:28 2019] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20171023 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[Sat Feb  9 15:25:29 2019] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[Sat Feb  9 15:25:29 2019] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
[Sat Feb  9 15:25:29 2019] [drm] RC6 on
[Sat Feb  9 15:25:37 2019] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Loading driver
[Sat Feb  9 15:25:37 2019] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
```